# Telerik RadGridView style column cell

Tags: c#

How can I make a cell text font bold for specific column in Telerik `RadGridView`?
I tried with inserting Style property in xaml file of telerik gridview but when I try to get that style values by name I am getting null.

```
<Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

```
Style s = RadGridView.Resources["style1"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it by creating custom StyleSelector class in which I kept FontWeight property as per my requirement.